# before_create not being invoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this class

```
class APIKey < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create do 
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    self.valid_token = true
  end
end
```

and when I try to create a new record with `APIKey.create!` I get this erro

```
  SQL (56.5ms)  INSERT INTO "api_keys" ("created_at", "token", "updated_at", "valid_token") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", nil], ["token", nil], ["updated_at", nil], ["valid_token", nil]]
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "token" violates not-null constraint
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation of the record happens before the `before_create` callback is called. You should set your attributes in the `before_validation` callback.

If you want more information about ActiveRecord's callbacks you may check [RailGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: Kind of worked...now, the objects that I previously setted (`token` and `valid_token`) are OK, but the timestamp fields are empty...